# Join, Group by and Sum in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group overtime work hours of employees by employeeId and get data of employeeNames and total monthly overtime work hours of employees. But this Linq query gives translation error.

```cs
var results = 
    from overtime in context.Overtimes
    join employeeCredential in context.EmployeeCredentials
        on overtime.EmployeeId equals employeeCredential.id
    join employeeDetail in context.EmployeeDetails
        on employeeCredential.id equals employeeDetail.employeeId
    where overtime.Month == month && overtime.Year == year
    group new { overtime, employeeCredential, employeeDetail } by overtime.EmployeeId into g
    select new MonthlyOvertimeWorkHours
    {
        EmployeeName = g.First().employeeDetail.employeeName,
        TotalWorkHourOfMonth = g.Sum(t => t.overtime.OvertimeWorkHour)
    };
```

Error

> { "error": employeeCredential\r\n IsNullable: True\r\n , \r\n
> employeeDetail = EntityShaperExpression: \r\n EntityType:
> EmployeeDetail\r\n ValueBufferExpression: \r\n
> ProjectionBindingExpression: employeeDetail\r\n IsNullable: True\r\n
> }\r\n .Select(s => s.employeeDetail.employeeName)\r\n .First()' could
> not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
> translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
> call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or
> 'ToListAsync'. }

Comment: What error did it gave?

Comment: "Errors and Failures", $400: "What translation error does this query give?"

Comment: {
  "error":  employeeCredential\r\n        IsNullable: True\r\n    , \r\n    employeeDetail = EntityShaperExpression: \r\n        EntityType: EmployeeDetail\r\n        ValueBufferExpression: \r\n            ProjectionBindingExpression: employeeDetail\r\n        IsNullable: True\r\n }\r\n    .Select(s => s.employeeDetail.employeeName)\r\n    .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. 
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until EF Core 6, you cannot access to records after grouping (which is usually bad). Only aggregates and `Key` is available.

To fix issue just add `employeeName` to grouping key.

```cs
var results = 
    from overtime in context.Overtimes
    join employeeCredential in context.EmployeeCredentials
        on overtime.EmployeeId equals employeeCredential.id
    join employeeDetail in context.EmployeeDetails
        on employeeCredential.id equals employeeDetail.employeeId
    where overtime.Month == month && overtime.Year == year
    group new { overtime, employeeCredential, employeeDetail } by new { overtime.EmployeeId, employeeDetail.employeeName } into g
    select new MonthlyOvertimeWorkHours
    {
        EmployeeName = g.Key.employeeName,
        TotalWorkHourOfMonth = g.Sum(t => t.overtime.OvertimeWorkHour)
    };
```